# Windows UWP App from Visual Studio already installed, can't be uninstalled and won't run

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, windows-10

Alright so I have an app called Currency Converter that I made in Visual Studio using UWP. When I try and run it from within Visual Studio I get a dialog box saying "The app "c347c8-blah blah" is already installed on this machine etc"

[image: link]

When I select no nothing happens. When I select yes I get the following error:

```
Error       DEP0900: Failed to unregister application "c347c8cc-961b-43a1-ae91-d83c61cffbf8_1.0.0.0_x86__eq9h3e6grdrp4". 
            [0x80073CFA] Unspecified error  CurrencyConverter
```

I did notice that two versions of this app seem to be installed on my computer, [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsKob.png) they are visible in the apps list in the start menu and in settings. Clicking these apps opens a window for a fraction of a second then it dissapears. Uninstalling them from here has no effect. When i try to uninstall from  Apps & Features I get the error code `0x80073cfa`.

I've tried cleaning, rebuilding and redeploying the project and the entire solution. This happens without error but the problem persists. I found this alleged solution to the problem [link](http://woshub.com/remove-appxpackage-0x80073cfa-removal-failed/) though it would seem that this would be detrimental. [link](https://superuser.com/a/1222890)

[Edit] I've tried running this app on other computers and it runs fine there.

Comment: Does your computer contains multiple user accounts ? Please try to edit your project's package name and rebuild it.

Comment: No, just one user account. And that fixed it. Thanks. Do you know why that worked?

Comment: I have encountered a similar problem, I have multiple accounts on the host and other accounts have already installed this application. If I want to install this installation package for my account, I need to modify the package name to prevent conflicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that there is the same package name app was installed in the computer for other user, if you want to install the app, please try to uninstall the previous version or edit current app's package name to prevent conflicts.

Double click your app's Package.appxmanifes-> packaging tab->edit Package name.

Comment: I assure you there are no other user accounts on this machine. I'm now getting this error having made a new project several times with the same name.

Comment: Please check the project publish name is same with the previous version.